# ¿Se pueden obtener graficas de datos en python y guardarlas como imagen?

Tags: python, imagen, flask, backend, datos

El asunto es que yo recojo los datos de la DB, y a través del código de backend trato esos datos para generar una gráfica de esos datos y al final me acabe generando una imagen de esa gráfica, podría hacerse eso? o debería devolver un json con todos los datos y generar la gráfica en el frontend y a raíz de ahí guardar la imagen de esa gráfica? Estoy utilizando flask para el proyecto.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para la primera opción que comentas, sí, se puede hacer, te recomiendo que utilices la librería 'matplotlib.pyplot' con el método 'savefig'.

Comment: He estado mirando sobre eso que me has dicho y si creo que sería eso, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Perdón Hernando soy algo novato todavia redactando, pero con la solución que me dio @cls ya me puse a indagar y lo encontré